# Giving code to a Button/ToolStripMenuItem using another Sub

Tags: vb.net

So, i wanted to make my application play Video Files. You select one via a ToolStripMenuItem. I made the Code pretty much an allrounder for all the 500 ToolStripMenuItems.
The Code I'm up to:

```
Dim Inst As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectorys.ProgramFiles + "\folder\"

Private Sub PlayVid(Name)
    AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = Inst + IO.File.ReadAllLines(Inst + "directorys.txt")(Name.Txt.Substring(0, 3))
End Sub

Private Sub ToolStripMenuItem1_Click(sender As System.Objekt) ToolStripMenuItem1.Click
    Call PlayVid(Ctype(sender, ToolStripMenuItem))
End Sub
```

So now the code I need to assign to each ToolStripMenuItem is short, but still I would need to do this for over 500 of them. So my question is, if there is a way (maybe in Form.Load) to assign this(*Call PlayVid(Ctype(sender, ToolStripMenuItem))*) code to everyone. Something like:

```
Private Sub Form_Load() Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim T As Control
    For Each T in Controls
        If TypeOf C is ToolStripMenuItem Then
            C.Code = Call PlayVid(Ctype(sender, ToolStripMenuItem))
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Is something like that even possible? And if so, how does it work?

Answer (score 0):

500 menu items?  Wow.

Anyway, when you create your menu items, one of the parameters is for the click handler:

```
Dim tsm As New ToolStripMenuItem("YourFile", Nothing, AddressOf PlayVid)
```

Your PlayVid method should have the appropriate parameters to match the click event:

```
Private Sub PlayVid(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

End Sub
```

ToolStripMenuItems aren't controls in the traditional sense.  Reference your parent menu item:

```
For Each menuItem As ToolStripMenuItem In ToolStripDropDownButton1.DropDownItems

Next
```

Comment: @user2217656 You didn't show how you made 500 menu items.  How did you create them?

Comment: Simply by Hand giving each and every one a text.

Comment: @user2217656 Ouch.  In your code, replace the `C.Code` line with `AddHandler C.Click, AddressOf PlayVid`.

Comment: for clarificationso ive got that application to play an series. every text on a menuitem is like that: "002: I'm okay". In a text document ive listed additional information about the directory in which the vid file is saved, it was previously mentionad as "directorys.txt". In every line is the directory of one episode so i can get it by using the episode number and the readalllines command. The code i created could be used on every one of these menuitems(dont know how to call it "a generic code" maybe?)So know i have to assign that short piece of generic(?) code to all the menu items

Comment: how would you have created all those menu items, i dont know another way

Comment: @user2217656 If I understand correctly, the video files are all listed in that text file?  Loop through each line using `File.ReadAllLines` and inside the loop, you would create the menu item (the way I showed) and then add that menu item to the DropDownItems collection of your parent ToolStripButton.  If unclear, try documenting that issue in a new question since this question was about adding the click event to each of those existing menu item.  Hope that helps. Do consider 500 menu items as excessive and a ListBox would probably be more appropriate.

Comment: ive got youre point seems logical for me but probably the last problem is one that i'm completely clueless about rightnow because the "If TypeOf C is Toolstripmenuitem Then" gives me an error that i cant use toolstripmenuitem in there. As i said im clueless rightnow have you got a tip for me how to do that?

P.S.You are right now like a hero for me, and i wish i could return the favour sometime.

Comment: @user2217656 It should be `If TypeOf T Is..` since you declared T as your looping variable.  Consider changing the name of T to childControl or something more distinct.  T is usually used for generics.

Comment: @user2217656 Sorry, updated post.  ToolStripMenuItems aren't controls, so that loop won't work.  Just reference the parent ToolStrip object that has the menu items.